# Preventing 0px height in my container divs

Tags: css, clearfix

On my homepage we have 4 container divs holding our images and content. The page displays and looks fine, but when I hover over each container using "inspect element" the div width is showing fine but the height shows as 0px.

Do I need to add clearfix to fix this issue or perhaps height:auto? Is clearfix automatically defined in CSS or do I need to add it to my stylesheet? Clearfix always seemed a big foggy to me.

display: inline-block seems to fill the height, when added to each div. but not sure if that is suitable over adding float:left.

I have pasted the divs and css for each below

```
<div class="category-4">
clear: both;
width: 100%;

<div class="mydownloads">
width: 100%;
margin-top: 17px;


<div class="category-2">

clear: both;
width: 100%;

<div class="category-3">

clear: both;
width: 100%;


<div class="mybrands">
clear: both;
width: 100%;
```

Comment: if it displays fine, what are you actually trying to _fix_? Do you have `float:xx` elements inside the divs - this will set the container div to `0px`. If you post the full html and css of one of these divs, it will be easier to explain what is happening

Comment: You have not mentioned floats at all, so I don't see why anything would need to be cleared.

Comment: Do they have any content in them? Or a min-height set? I'm going to assume they all have closing tags, even if not displayed above.

Comment: if you have used float then surely u need to use clearfix